# Does cortical nephron has just thin ascending loop of Henle?

Tags: kidney

[image]

Guyton and Hall , South Asian edition states that, in Table 76-1 that ascending limb of loop of Henle has thin segment only. But, none diagram in book or internet explain this.

Can any one explain this difference in text and diagram please?

[image]

Note: AK Jain Textbook of physiology 6th edition. states on Table 55.1

> The descending limb of loop of henle contains a thin segment whereas ascending limb contains a thick segment.

This does explain diagram a bit.

This makes Guyton contradictory.

Edit: From comments, no where the table states part of loh in medulla.

Comment: https://goo.gl/Yiz7f5 ascending limb is 'thick' not thin only. See the diagram.

Comment: @JM97 So, is the given information on table wrong?

Comment: There is also no link on wikipedia or anyother site for cortical nephron ,I could find.

Comment: @Anubhav Goel no! that is not what it implies.for the cortical nephron only the thin limb is present in the medulla but both thick and thin limbs are present in the medulla for the juxta medullary nephron so it provides for functional diffrrences between the nephrons.REFER TO THE DIAGRAM ON PAGE 463.(Fig-76-5)

Comment: @CATHARANTHUS It is no where written in table part in medulla.

Comment: @Anubhav https://ntp.niehs.nih.gov/nnl/urinary/kidney/index.htm see the figure 3.

Comment: Most probably the wording is wrong.

Comment: @JM97 Ok, you can add that whole as an answer, if you wish or have time?  Thanks for help.

Comment: @Anubhav Goel JM97 is correct...besides its a table to help you memorise not understand concepts...thats why i precisely mentioned the diagram in your edited question.

Comment: @CATHARANTHUS A table memorising wrong things actually.. Well,  thanks for your efforts.